# Is there a way to use embedded instance of Neo4j in c# with or without the Neo4j Driver?

Tags: c#, neo4j

Following is the code snippet of query using Neo4j Driver in C#

```
string query = $"MATCH(c:Customer) RETURN c";
using (var session = driver.Session())
{
    var result = session.Run(query);
}
```

Can the embedded instance be created in the above code ? The embedded instance can be created in Java using GraphDatabaseFactory. Is there something similar in C#?
The reason I am looking for it is from performance perspective. If there is an embedded instance of Neo4j in the application, then the Neo4j would run on the same process of the client application.

Comment: Since the query was posted in 2015, so thought of checking back if there is any update on it.

Comment: yep but the response is still valid ...